# change tab color in chrome by extension in script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am developing extension for chrome browser.
Is there a way to change tab colour in chromium from script by using extension?
(something like chrome.tabs.setcolor(tab.id, 'red'))

I want to change colour when some events triggers (colour can be changed several times and it can be different each time equals the type of event which triggered it). So I can't use theme because I think that theme set tab colour forever and it can't be changed in future.

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeBackgroundColor

Comment: No, this is not what I want. this function changes colour for BrowserAction button which is right from address bar, and I want to change colour for tab where html page's title is written.

Comment: I was confused that's why i haven't put this as a answer

Comment: :) Such question was posted here half a year ago and somebody suggested to use themes. it is interesting if this has changed for now.